# Rails Blog: Edit is Creating a Duplicate Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, duplicates, edit, blogs

Making a blog in Rails and the Edit feature duplicates a post then saves the changes into a new record. I want the edit so simply edit the original post, not do any duplication.

Wondering if someone can help me out.

Here is some code... Just let me know if I need to post anything else!

*posts_controller.rb*

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end

def new
    if user_signed_in?
        @post = Post.new
    else
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    if user_signed_in?
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    else
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :category, :body))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    if user_signed_in?
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to posts_path
    else
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
end

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :category, :body)
    end
end
```

*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :category %>
        <%= f.select :category, ['x', 'y', 'z'] %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p class="actions"><%= link_to 'Back to Posts', posts_path %> | <%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

*routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts, :lines
  get 'home/index'

  devise_for :users

  root 'home#index'

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/admin" => "devise/sessions#new"
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the routes?

Comment: Where's the form for a `:post` record? You posted one for `:line`.

Comment: @Jason oops, you're right. They're similar forms (copied posts to make lines) and I was getting the edit problem for both my lines and posts records anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is being built with a `POST` action because your first argument in `form_for` is the symbol `:post` instead of the instance `@post`. If you have the form in a partial because you want to use the fields for both the edit and new views, you should put the Ruby for the fields in the partial, but put the `form_for` calls in the edit and new views. In the edit view, you should use

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

so it builds the form for the existing record and not a new record.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide different `form action paths` for the new and edit form:

```
<%= form_for :line, url: lines_path do |f| %>
```

The mistake is in the `url`.

If you set the routes by convention, for example with `resources :posts` in your routes file than you can remove the `url` parameter from the form helper method and Rails handles it for you.

If your routes don't comply to the `REST` conventions. Than you should probably provide the url as local variable to the partial.

**Your create view:**

```
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { url: path_to_create_action } %>
```

**Your update view:**

```
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { url: path_to_update_action } %>
```

**And in your _form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for :line, url: url do |f| %>
  <!-- ... -->
<% end %>
```

You will find more information in the [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).